# Mac capable Access similar database software

Tags: osx, database, microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

How do I create a database application that satisfies these requirements?

- It must be capable of running on windows and mac operating systems.
- It must be similar visually to excel. The user needs to be able to enter
  data as if they were entering data into a spreadsheet.
- It must be a relational database.
- It needs data validation capabilities.
- It needs to be able to handle over 15,000 entries

Microsoft Access is perfect for my needs, except for there is no mac version. SharePoint is almost perfect, except for it will not hold so many entries and is not relational. Excel almost works, except it is not relational either, and is not really a database software. I also looked online for database software, and none of the ones I've seen have excel like data entry.

Comment: Have you looked at FileMaker Pro?

Comment: Is this for standalone use, deployed to a single computer without networked shared access?

Answer (score 1):

[LibreOffice Base](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/) provides a database solution, either to its own database or as a front end for a number of other databases.

- It is available on Windows, OS-X & Linux
- It is Free, gratis & open source
- Integrates with the rest of the LibreOffice tools
- You can have a spreadsheet like view or you can design forms.
- Depending on the database selected you should be able to add should, depending on the size of each entry, far exceed your 15k requirement, see https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/59836/is-there-a-limit-of-the-data-in-the-database/ for more information.

Comment: Base seems pretty good, except for I'm having trouble with data validation. How do I specify, for example, that a date must occur before today?

Comment: @AviS. Where in a query, in data load?

Comment: @AviS. https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/e/e8/BH40-BaseHandbook.pdf or other ebooks on the subject may help